# simple if/else misusage in python

Tags: python, if-statement, return

I have a problem with if and else statements.

I wrote the following script:

```
def questionscp():
    stateanswer = raw_input('Do you want to change device state? (y/n): ')
    if stateanswer == 'y':
        choosestate = raw_input('Choose Device State(0=Hibernate, 1=Power Save, 2=Safe Mode, 3=Operating Mode, 4=Diagnostic Mode, 5=Remote Power Off): ')
        client.write_register(64, choosestate, 70)
    else:
        return
    activewarningflag = raw_input('Activate warning flag?? (y/n): ')
    if activewarningflag == 'y':
        client.write_register(67, 1, 70)
    else:
        return
```

The problem is that I want the script will ask the second question (activewarningflag) after the first one, even if 'n' is chosen, but in the else statement I put "return" cause Im new to do this and dont know a lot yet. What can I write instead of "return" if I want the function to continue to read itself?

thanks

Comment: You don't need to have an else statement at all, its also possible you don't even need a return

Comment: you might want to use a while loop and verify input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put `pass` as in

```
else:
        pass
```

This will make the interpreter ignore your `else` clause.

Or

you can **ignore** the `else` altogether, as Python semantics allows an `if` statement without an `else` clause

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need the else statement at all

```
if stateanswer == 'y':
    choosestate = raw_input('...')
    client.write_register(64, choosestate, 70)
activewarningflag = raw_input('Activate warning flag?? (y/n): ')
```

You can leave it out and it will continue as normal.

You also may not even need the return (depending on what your method does). Returning is normally either done to return a value from the method or to exit the method early.